# How can I access memory?

Tags: c, string, capitalize

I made a method which changed small letter to capital letter. For example, when I input 'i love c language' in method, then it outputs 'I Love C Language'.

Finally, I made whole method, but it had error. I don't know the reason why it couldn't operate... Help me..!

I already build this code in Visual Studio 2019.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void LetterCapitalizer(char* str)
{
    const int convertCapital = 32;
    const char emptySpace = ' ';

    str[0] = str[0] + convertCapital;

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if(i == emptySpace)
            str[i+1] = str[i+1] + convertCapital;
    }

    printf("%s", str);
}

int main(void)
{
    LetterCapitalizer("i am a boy");

    return 0;
}
```

I want to print I Am A Boy in console window, but it doesn't appeared.

Comment: If you hit a space, you're gonna convert the *next character*. Then the loop proceeds to the next character, and converts it again. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: `"i am a boy"` is a **string literal** and it is "read-only". Try `char tmp[] = "i am a boy"; LetterCapitalizer(tmp);` because the contents of `tmp` can be changed

Comment: I want to changed parameter, but I can't. I can only use char*str in parameter.

Comment: One problem is you don't know how to use a debugger. Instead of guessing or asking on SO, learn how to use the excellent debugger built into Visual Studio. Try this: start your program with the F11 key (Step In). Then use F10 (Step Over) to step through your program. It will display your variable values at each step. Keep stepping and looking and you will find at least some of your bugs right away.

Answer (score 2):

This method with `convertCapital` isn't portable, for instance it didn't work on my machine (I had to subtract 32, not add 32). Use `toupper` instead:

```
#include <ctype.h>
....
str[0] = toupper(str[0]);
```

And also

```
str[i + 1] = toupper(str[i + 1]);
```

Furthermore, this here

```
if(i == emptySpace)
```

Should be

```
if(str[i] == emptySpace)
```

But about your actual problem: `"i am a boy"` can't be modified, but you can do this instead:

```
char string[] = "i am a boy";
LetterCapitalizer(string);
```

Or you can duplicate the string inside your `LetterCapitalizer` function:

```
void LetterCapitalizer(char* str)
{
    char *strCopy = malloc(strlen(str) + 1); // make a mutable copy of the string
    strcpy(strCopy, str);
    const int convertCapital = 32;
    const char emptySpace = ' ';

    strCopy[0] = toupper(strCopy[0]);

    for (int i = 0; strCopy[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (strCopy[i] == emptySpace)
            strCopy[i + 1] = toupper(strCopy[i + 1]);
    }
    printf("%s", strCopy);
    free(strCopy); // free the memory again
}
```

---

If you want, you can avoid allocating more memory altogether like this:

```
void LetterCapitalizer(char* str)
{
    const char emptySpace = ' ';
    putchar(toupper(str[0]));

    for (int i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        putchar(str[i]);
        if (str[i] == emptySpace) {
            putchar(toupper(str[i + 1]));
            i++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, it gives a segmentation fault as you free the 'strCopy' variable before printing it...

Comment: I typically avoid allocation inside a function that returns `void` because there's typically no way to get an error out (if the `malloc()` fails) without crashing the program.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister good point. I posted a version without additional memory allocation to show how that could look like.

Answer (score 1):

Two small things to improve your programm :
First, as @pmg said, replace the `LetterCapitalizer("i am a boy");` by

```
char tmp[] = "i am a boy";
LetterCapitalizer(tmp);
```

This will allow you not to write into a `read-only` string litteral.

Secondly, if you string contains a `space`, you will convert **the next caracter**... In this case you could just skip the current iteration and go to the next one.
Finally, if you don't have any restrictions on C-functions call, there is a function `toupper()` which takes a caracter and converts it into upper case !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag for indicating that next non-space character is to be capitalized. You can store the result string in another string. and then return that result string. I have corrected the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void LetterCapitalizer(char* str)
{
    const int convertCapital = 32;
    const char emptySpace = ' ';
    bool flag = true;
    char str2[strlen(str)]; 
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        if(flag) {
            str2[i] = str[i] - convertCapital;
            flag = false;
        }
        else {
            str2[i] = str[i];
        }
        if(str[i] == emptySpace)
            flag = true;
    }

    printf("%s", str2);
}

int main(void)
{
    LetterCapitalizer("i am a boy");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to import `<stdbool.h>` for `bool` and `string.h` for `strlen()` function

Comment: Also, you need to subtract 32 because in ASCII, captial letters come before small so their ASCII code is 32 letters behind. You can see the full ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/)